# Detect push notification selection when the app is at running state in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I am using `didReceiveRemoteNotification` for detecting the app notification. But it is is getting fired automatically, when the app is at running state. I need the **notification selection** get detected when the app is at running state, rather than automatic notification detection through `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 10+ provide the custom local notification for handling this type of issue when the app is running in the foreground.

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, add the delegate

```
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
```

then create an appDelegate extension and add this.

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

// Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo



    // Print full message.
    print(userInfo)

    // Change this to your preferred presentation option
    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                               didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                               withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
       let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo


       // Print full message.
       print("tap on on forground app",userInfo)

       completionHandler()
   }

}
```

For details:

[Read This Tutorial](https://iosarchitect.com/show-push-notifications-when-app-running-in-foreground-ios-swift/)

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I am using this. But the issue is, I can't handle the notification selection when the app is running.

Comment: @KaranAlangat above answer is correct didReceive response should call , have you check?

Comment: yes. Only the notification selection is not getting detected.

Comment: I am using the same code in my app. Put breakpoint and check if the function is being called or not.

Comment: Thank you so much. It as issue with delegate. :)